# Remove numbers from column in r

Tags: r

I did some web scraping using the code below and now I want to remove the numbers in the beginning of the strings. The column looks like this:

```
1. Huddle           
2. Shortlist Media          
3. Three Sixty Entertainment            
4. Naked Wines
```

This is the code:

`tab10 <- h %>% html_nodes("h2") %>% html_text() %>% data.frame() %>% map_df(rev)`

Can anyone help? thanks!

Comment: Try `stringr::str_remove(c("1. A", "2. B"), "^\\d+\\.\\s")` which remove any string which consists of a number followed by a dot and a space at the beginning of a string.

Comment: Or base function `sub('^\\d+\\.\\s+', '', df[[1]])`, if the data set is named `df` and the column is column 1.